# Inconsistent Graph API Behavior for Album Requests

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a listing of photo albums using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID/albums
```

It is working perfectly for some users, and other users I am getting nothing:

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

I am sure in both cases the user ID is correct and valid. For the users that return nothing I can see the albums when logged in as the same user, so  I don't see how permissions could be an issue.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you making the request with a token for the owner of the album, or are you trying to get albums for a friend of the current user? If the latter, the friend might just have their security settings set so that they don’t share photos with apps a friend is using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Graph API - empty JSON array for public albums of non-friends](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8843509/facebook-graph-api-empty-json-array-for-public-albums-of-non-friends)

Comment: Crap, sorry, i mis-merged, CBroe's comment is correct if it's the user's friends

Comment: I meant to merge to http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10939051/why-am-i-unable-to-see-friends-albums-via-facebook-graph-api

Comment: CBroe: the latter. I looked at all the privacy settings, and I did not see something for an app group, just friends and friends of friends.

Comment: You appear to be correct Igy, thanks. I found the setting and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You'll get better results by writing it this way:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/USER_ID?fields=albums.fields(id)
```

I got this result while playing with the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer).
Here,

[image]

you've to generate a new token with **user_photos** and **friends_photos** selected.
Then, select what you need in the list:

[image]

And it seems to display what you need (at least if the ID you are looking for is the one of your friends)!

Comment: I am trying to test that in a web browser with a valid access_token. Do you know how to add the access_token to that, everything I have tried results in an error. Also, I assume the only thing I change is the USER_ID and not the id variable, correct?

Comment: Am I missing something? This is giving me NULL results: https://graph.facebook.com/9988776655?fields=albums.fields(id) the number 9988776655 is a valid user ID.

Comment: By the way, do you care to explain how the results from this would be any different?

Answer (score 1):

Igy appears to be correct. This is a duplicate of [10939051](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/10939051/why-am-i-unable-to-see-friends-albums-via-facebook-graph-api).

Since I could not find it, the setting that will exclude all user photos and albums from apps can be found by going to Privacy Settings > Apps, Games and Websites > How people bring your info to the apps they use > De-check My photos.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]