# Facebook album data returns empty in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, android-facebook

Facebook URL mentioned below return empty data but there is album images in Facebook, i am using new Facebook SDK 3.5.2. anyone have suggestion please help me to come out of this issue.
Thanks on advance

"https://graph.facebook.com/ID/albums?access_token=Token";

Comment: You should paste your request code.

Comment: @DamienR. Thanks for your reply, which request code i have to paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem. Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13692132/inconsistent-graph-api-behavior-for-album-requests). Some users dont allow access to their albums and photos through apps. You will have to code accordingly.

```
            Session.NewPermissionsRequest np = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, "friends_photos");
            Session.getActiveSession().requestNewReadPermissions(np);
            Request rq = new Request(Session.getActiveSession(), userID + "/albums", null, HttpMethod.GET, new Request.Callback() {

                @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {

            }
            });
            rq.executeAsync();

        }
```

Here is what it should look like. just change userID to the user whose albums you want to retrieve with response being the data that is returned.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i check with that settings everything same. do you know how to add permission in facebook sdk 3.5

Answer (score 0):

```
I got result by adding below this permissions but i need album list now i get only cover photo and profile picture.

 if(session != null && !session.isOpened()){
  OpenRequest openRequest = new OpenRequest(this).setCallback(statusCallback);
 if (openRequest != null) {
    openRequest.setDefaultAudience(SessionDefaultAudience.EVERYONE);
    openRequest.setPermissions(Arrays.asList("friends_hometown","user_photos","friends_photos"));
    openRequest.setLoginBehavior(SessionLoginBehavior.SSO_WITH_FALLBACK);
    session.openForRead(openRequest);
}
}
```